# Why isn't iCheck iradio_square-blue working

Tags: jquery, icheck

I am trying to implement [iCheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/) on my website by using the Square skin deployed With iCheck.

The probelm is that the radio doesn't get the css styling and I am not able to figure out why. Here is my code:

In my document.ready function I have the following code:

```
$(function(){
 $('input1').iCheck({
radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
increaseArea: '20%' // optional
                });

    });
```

I call the .js and the .css like this and I have verified that the paths are correct.

```
<link href="plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="plugins/iCheck/icheck.js"></script>
```

The html looks like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="input1" id="input1" checked></br>
```

Does anyone have a clue what might cause this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`id` selector should start with `#` in jquery.

The code

```
$('input1').iCheck({
```

should changed to

```
 $('#input1').iCheck({
```

Comment: I am afraid that didn't change anything

Comment: Ok, it was a classic mistake. I called the jquery code before the js was included. Thank you anyways